# Recursive Queries with Window functions

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

So, I have a table:

```
   DATE     STORE   PRODUCT
01.01.2020  Store1  Product1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product2
01.01.2020  Store1  Product3
01.01.2020  Store1  Product4
01.02.2020  Store1  Product5
01.02.2020  Store1  Product6
01.02.2020  Store1  Product7
01.02.2020  Store1  Product8
01.01.2020  Store2  Product1
01.01.2020  Store2  Product2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product3
01.01.2020  Store2  Product4
03.01.2020  Store2  Product1
01.03.2020  Store2  Product2
02.03.2020  Store2  Product8
03.03.2020  Store2  Product10
06.08.2020  Store2  Product6
08.11.2020  Store2  Product7
```

I need to to Count Distinct stores.
Moreover, if more than 20 days have passed between previous  rows, then the value of store  is unique

What I expect:

```
   date Store   Product Product_x
01.01.2020  Store1  Product1    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product2    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product3    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product4    1
01.02.2020  Store1  Product5    1e
01.02.2020  Store1  Product6    1e
01.02.2020  Store1  Product7    1e
01.02.2020  Store1  Product8    1e
01.01.2020  Store2  Product1    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product2    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product3    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product4    2
03.01.2020  Store2  Product1    2
01.03.2020  Store2  Product2    2e
02.03.2020  Store2  Product8    2e
03.03.2020  Store2  Product10   2e
06.08.2020  Store2  Product6    2ee
08.11.2020  Store2  Product7    2eee
```

What I have and my query:

```
    DATE_   STORE   PRODUCT TT
01.01.2020  Store1  Product1    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product2    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product3    1
01.01.2020  Store1  Product4    1
01.02.2020  Store1  Product8    1e
01.02.2020  Store1  Product7    1
01.02.2020  Store1  Product5    1
01.02.2020  Store1  Product6    1
01.01.2020  Store2  Product4    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product3    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product2    2
01.01.2020  Store2  Product1    2
03.01.2020  Store2  Product1    2
01.03.2020  Store2  Product2    2e
02.03.2020  Store2  Product8    2
03.03.2020  Store2  Product10   2
06.08.2020  Store2  Product6    2e
08.11.2020  Store2  Product7    2e
```

Query:

```
 select p.*, case
                  when p.date_ - lag(p.date_, 1) over ( partition by p.store order by p.date_)>20
                  then to_char(dense_rank() over (order by p.store)) || 'e'
                  else to_char(dense_rank() over (order by p.store)) end tt 
from table p;
```

How is it possible to solve this problem?
And how to apply a recursive function to add "e" if the difference between the dates is more than 20 days?

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible to solve this problem?

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       store,
       product,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY store) || LPAD('e', mn - 1, 'e') AS tt
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY store
         ORDER BY dt, product
         MEASURES
           MATCH_NUMBER() AS mn
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (first_row within_20_day* )
         DEFINE
           within_20_day AS dt <= PREV(dt) + INTERVAL '20' DAY
       )
```

Or, in earlier versions, using the `LAG` and `SUM` analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       store,
       product,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY store)
       || LPAD(
            'e',
            SUM(has_changed_grp) OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY dt, product) - 1,
            'e'
          ) AS tt
FROM   (
  SELECT dt,
         store,
         product,
         CASE
         WHEN dt <= LAG(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY store ORDER BY dt, product)
                    + INTERVAL '20' DAY
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END AS has_changed_grp
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (dt, STORE, PRODUCT) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store1', 'Product1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store1', 'Product2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store1', 'Product3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store1', 'Product4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', 'Store1', 'Product5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', 'Store1', 'Product6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', 'Store1', 'Product7' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-02-01', 'Store1', 'Product8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store2', 'Product1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store2', 'Product2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store2', 'Product3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-01', 'Store2', 'Product4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-03', 'Store2', 'Product1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-01', 'Store2', 'Product2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-02', 'Store2', 'Product8' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-03-03', 'Store2', 'Product10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-08-06', 'Store2', 'Product6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-11-08', 'Store2', 'Product7' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| DT | STORE | PRODUCT | TT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product3 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product4 | 1 |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product5 | 1e |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product6 | 1e |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product7 | 1e |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00 | Store1 | Product8 | 1e |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product3 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product4 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product1 | 2 |
| 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product2 | 2e |
| 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product8 | 2e |
| 2020-03-03 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product10 | 2e |
| 2020-08-06 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product6 | 2ee |
| 2020-11-08 00:00:00 | Store2 | Product7 | 2eee |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YkNSYWmE)

> And how to apply a recursive function to add "e" if the difference between the dates is more than 20 days?

You probably could do it with recursion but it is likely going to be harder than using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` or alternatively, `LAG`/`LEAD` and analytic functions.